# where t : multiple classes

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

```
List<T> Foo<T>(Ilist list) 
where T : ??
```

is there any way to enforce T to be
one of few classes ?

eventually i want to do a switch on T..

thanks.

Comment: Are those `few classes` related or do they share a common base class or interface that all of them implement ?

Comment: Just be aware that you can sometimes go too far with Generics. I've been working on something recently and had a complex generic structure  where I had ClassA<P,S,R> where P<S>, S<R>. It was all nice and generic, but ended up being over engineered and I couldn;t use it effectively. Instead I had to split the code 3 ways and accept repeating similar code in different classes.

Comment: Here's a quick rule of thumb - if you think of doing `switch` on `T`, or even checking it with an `if`, you're doing generics wrong. Take a step back and figure how.

Comment: @Kobi: To that I would add that when a parameter instance is received as type T, the instance is guaranteed to be either T or a type derived from T; there's no guarantee T will be the exact type.  Using generics with constraints may eliminate the need for testing the type of a particular instance, but if in the absence of generics one would have to test the run-time type of a parameter, testing the run-time type of T won't change the need to test the type of the parameter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Enforcing a type constraint in this way indicates that those several classes are related with common functionality.

You should implement a common Interface and then restrict the type to that Interface:

```
public interface IUseful
{
    public void UsefulMethod();
}

List<T> Foo<T>(IList list) where T : IUseful
{
    // You now have access to all common functionality defined in IUseful
}
```

The added benefit is that now you don't have to switch on `T` to implement different behaviors. You can have the children of `IUseful` implement their own behaviors and then call each on their own.

Comment: I've been looking for something similar. I agree a common interface is the best solution. Though currently I'm using two libraries, and I can't change their code to use the common interface. So is there a way to do this without an interface?

Answer (score 15):

You can require that each class you want to allow into your list implements some interface `ISomething` and then create a `List<ISomething>`.

> eventually i want to do a switch on T..

Instead of a switch on the type of the object it might be better to have a method in your interface and implement it differently for each class.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, T could be a common base class or interface that you list objects share. You could have `List<IFoo>`, and the list could contain classes `Foo, Bar, and Baz` if they each implement the `IFoo` interface. Short of using inheritance, you would be stuck with a list of objects.

Answer (score 2):

What is it do you want? After the colon, you may enumerate the types to which you constraint `T` to.

For multiple classes, perhaps implementing one generic interface and setting your constraint to it might do the trick.

Please look at this link for further details: [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible. I would recommend deriving your limited set of classes from a common base class or interface.